# How to remove error at large time in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am working with solutions of a linearly damped wave equation. In the following code I use a "transparent" boundary condition at the end, which allows waves to pass through the specified boundary so that waves do not reflect back at the boundary:

```
pdeTest = D[u[x, t], t, t] + .031 D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x];

  soln2 = NDSolve[{pdeTest, u[x, 0] == Exp[-(x)^2],  Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][u][-200, t] == Derivative[0, 1][u][-200, t], 
  Derivative[1, 0][u][200, t] == -Derivative[0, 1][u][200, t]}, 
  u, {x, -200, 200}, {t, 0, 200}];

  Manipulate[ Plot[Evaluate[{u[x, t] /. soln2} /. t -> \[Tau]], {x, -200, 200}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-200, 200}, {0, 1.1}}, PlotStyle -> Red], {\[Tau], 0, 200} ]
```

This code seems to work without giving me a huge deviation using *Mathematica* version 8, but I have problems running it in version 9 at large times (`t=200`).

Intuitively, an initial wave pulse should split into two smaller wave pulses and the amplitudes of these two wave pulses should approach zero as `t` goes to infinity.

My code decided to blow up in *Mathematica* version 9. The behavior of the linearly damped wave equation is shown as expected when NDSolved and graphed in version 8.
Since I am working on this project in version 9, I wanted to know how to go about fixing this problem.

Comment: it works ok for me using V 10.01 on windows. moved the slider all the way to the right and I see no errors. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mDQjC.png)  may be you can upgrade to 10.01

Comment: There is a difference between v10 and v9. here is my plot from v9.0.1. [Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ujO26.png). But the behaviour of the waves you describe in your question works fine.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128516/1871