# Boundary Condition for Schrödinger Equation in Infinite Range

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to simulate the movement of a coherent state in a quantum harmonic oscilator, but for some reason the answer diverges and there is a warning about not enought boundary conditions.

Also, since I plan on moving to more complex situations in the future, I would like to avoid b.c.s of the kind:

```
p[t, L] == 0
```

The reason is that for higher energy situations it will be more taxing to keep L much greater than my area of interest an having the wave get too close to it would cause undesired reflexions.

My code, for a 1D case, is as follows:

```
w = 1;
L = 3;
c = 1;
usol = NDSolveValue[{I D[p[t, x], t] + 1/2 D[p[t, x], x, x] == 
    1/2 w^2 x^2 p[t, x], p[0, x] == E^(-w (x - c)^2/2)*(w/Pi)^(1/4)}
  , p, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -L, L}]
```

Comment: Yes, the b.c. isn't enough, for a initial value problem defined on $-\infty<x<\infty$ you need to add artificial b.c. approximating "infinity". There're many posts about this type of issue, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128516/1871

Comment: @xzczd, thank you for the hint! I adapted the b.c. and it worked, but I must admit to not undertanding why it did... abc = D[p[t,x], x] + direction p[t,x] == 
    0 /. {{x -> lb, direction -> -1}, {x -> rb, direction -> 1}};

Comment: I'm a bit surprised :D . I posted the example just to show that artificial boundary is needed, I didn't know ABC is also applicable for 1D Schrodinger's equation.

Comment: PLenty of references about it, like: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999108004804. But the subject is complex and I dont know if what I tried is a good answer...

Comment: Maybe you can ask a question e.g. "What's the state-of-art/most popular artificial boundary condition for 1D Schrodinger's equation" in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @xzczd, it seems they had lots of discussions about this already!!! I will find something that fits and post an answer here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since OP has found this [interesting post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/21246/5331), let me try to implement the exterior complex scaling method mentioned there.

First, make the transform $x=
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
  & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -R_0+e^{i \theta } (\xi +R_0) & -\xi >R_0 \\
 R_0+e^{i \theta } (\xi -R_0) & \xi >R_0 \\
 \xi  & -R_0\leq \xi\leq R_0 \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}\right.
$, I'll use [`DChange`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80267/1871) for the task:

```
set = {I D[p[t, x], t] + 1/2 D[p[t, x], x, x] == 1/2 w^2 x^2 p[t, x], 
   p[0, x] == E^(-w (x - c)^2/2)*(w/Pi)^(1/4)};

right = Exp[I θ] (ξ - R0) + R0;
left = Exp[I θ] (ξ + R0) - R0;
middle = ξ;

coevalue = CoefficientList[
   Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    Piecewise[{{right, ξ > R0}, {left, -ξ > R0}}, middle], ξ];

neweq = DChange[set, x == coe@0 + coe@1 ξ, x, ξ, p[t, x]] /. 
   Thread[(coe /@ {0, 1}) -> coevalue];

(* Alternative approach for deducing neweq: *)
help = DChange[#, x == #2, x, ξ, p[t, x]] &;
change = Piecewise[{{help[#, right], ξ > R0}, {help[#, left], -ξ > R0}}, 
    help[#, middle]] &;  

neweq = Simplify`PWToUnitStep@Map[change@# &, set, {2}];
```

Notice currently `DChange` doesn't directly support piecewise function so the coding is a little roundabout, but I think it's still simpler than transforming by hand.

> **Remark**
>
> `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` is an undocumented function that expands
>   `Piecewise` into a combination of `UnitStep`. I use this function to
>   "extract" `ξ` from the piecewise part, or `CoefficientList` in
>   first approach and `NDSolveValue` in second approach will fail.

The next step, which is also the final step, is to solve the equation:

```
w = 1;
L = 3;
c = 1;
tend = 20;
boundarylayer = L/5; thvalue = 1/2;
mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
        "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}
newsol = NDSolveValue[{neweq, 
      p[t, -L - boundarylayer] == p[t, L + boundarylayer] == 0} /. {R0 -> L, θ -> 
       thvalue}, p, {ξ, -L - boundarylayer, L + boundarylayer}, {t, 0, tend}, 
    Method -> mol[25, 4]]; // AbsoluteTiming
DensityPlot[Norm@newsol[t, x], {t, 0, tend}, {x, -L, L}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice I've manually set the number of spatial grid points, or `NDSolveValue` will automatically choose a too large one because the initial condition is no longer smooth.

Besides, the choosing of `R0` ($R_0$), `boundarylayer` (distance from $R_0$ to the boundary of computational domain) and `thvalue` ($\theta$) turns out to be a kind of art to make the reflection small enough. There might be some hint in the original paper about the method, but I simply find the proper value by trial and error.

Comment: (+1) You have transformed `x` and `t`to `xi` and `theta`, right?

Comment: @zhk Nope, in this transformation, only `x` is transformed to `ξ`. `θ` is a parameter. You can have a look at the linked post for more information.

Comment: Does this simplify the problem? In what way this transformation helps?

Comment: @zhk This transform makes the equation more complicated, of course :) , but by solving this equation instead, we obtain a better approximation for infinite range. (OP wants to solve the equation in $-\infty<x<\infty$. )

Comment: Wow, lots to learn from this answer! @xzczd, could you comment on the "mol" function? What does it do? Why did you use it?

Comment: @ivbc Actually this is a function I place in `SystemOpen@"init.m"` file, because I adjust these options frequently when using `NDSolve`. (See `Method -> mol[25, 4]`? It's the same as writing `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 25, "MinPoints" -> 25, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}`. ) I adjust these options because, as mentioned above, if I don't manually set `"MinPoints"` and `"MaxPoints"`, `NDSolveValue` will choose a too large one because the initial condition is not smooth. (You can take away the option and see what will happen. )

Comment: @xzczd, is it just me or is "Simplify`PWToUnitStep" an undocumented function??? Cant find it!

Comment: @ivbc Yeah, it's undocumented, but it has been explained and used in this site for several times: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Simplify%5C%60PWToUnitStep . I've added some explanation to my answer. If you still have trouble in understanding it, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 11):

Let's remember Schrodinger's equation:

$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(\mathbf{r},t) = \left [ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2 + V(\mathbf{r},t)\right ] \Psi(\mathbf{r},t)$

For the harmonic oscilator $V = x^2$, so your equation is missing a `p[x,t]` on the RHS besides the boundary conditions.
 `L` also needs to be larger too. This seems to work.

```
w = 2;
L = 10;
c = 3;
usol = NDSolveValue[{I D[p[t, x], t] + 1/2 D[p[t, x], x, x] == 
    1/2 w^2 x^2 p[t, x], 
   p[0, x] == Exp[(-w (x - c)^2/2)*(w/Pi)^(1/4)], p[t, L] == 0, 
   p[t, -L] == 0}, p, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -L, L}]

DensityPlot[Norm@usol[t, x], {t, 0, 10}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

**update**

For completeness purposes only, this is the solution with the abc boundary condition from @xzczd.

```
w = 1;
L = 3;
c = 1;
usol = NDSolveValue[{I D[p[t, x], t] + 1/2 D[p[t, x], x, x] - 
     1/2 w^2 x^2 p[t, x] == 0, 
   p[0, x] == E^(-w (x - c)^2/2)*(w/Pi)^(1/4), 
   Derivative[0, 1][p][t, -L] - p[t, -L] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][p][t, L] + p[t, L] == 0}, 
  p, {t, 0, 20}, {x, -L, L}]

DensityPlot[Norm@usol[t, x], {t, 0, 20}, {x, -L/2, L/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image]

Note how in the first case the wave function starts to diffuse as time passes, so it's not really a coherent state.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistake and for the solution. I improved the question a bit to tray to avoid the artificial b.c. p[t, L] == 0, as it must always be far from the area being analysed.

Comment: @ivb if with the ABC boundary condition it works, what is your question now? I don't understand.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa I guess it's because there's no guarentee that the simple ABC mentioned in my answer is always applicable. (It's a artificial boundary for 1D wave equation. ) Though currently it seems to work, it may be just a coincidence. (In the comment above, OP has found a paper about ABC for 1D Schrodinger's equation, in which the proposed ABC has a very different form. )

Comment: @xzczd your last comment nails it, I think we are now out of the scope of this site.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa, the state is coherent. The difusion is caused by the border condition's interference. Also, the code you posted seems to be corrupted somehow.

Comment: Answer accepted since it solves the problem. The question about why it works is important, and can be further considered here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/15973/transparent-boundary-conditions-for-finite-element-simulation-of-tdse/15978#15978

Comment: @ivbc Actually the spatial grid size has a significant influence on the first method, try adding `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 200, 
    "MinPoints" -> 200, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}` to `NDSolveValue`.