# Solving initial value problem partial differential equation with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of 3 coupled PDEs where I know the values of all three functions at `t = 0`.

```
sol = Flatten[NDSolve[{
    \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(sz[t, z]\)\) == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, z\)]\(sz[t, z]\)\) + n[t, z] + 
      sy[t, z] - sz[t, z], \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(sy[t, z]\)\) == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, z\)]\(sy[t, z]\)\) - 
      sz[t, z], \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(n[t, z]\)\) == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z, z\)]\(n[t, z]\)\) + sz[t, z] - 
      sy[t, z] , 
    sz[0, z] == DiracDelta[z], sy[0, z] == 0,
     n[0, z] == 0}
   , {sz[t], sy[t], n[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, {z, -100, 100}]]
```

I get nothing out but this error:
`NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`

I have successfully solved the equations using FTCS in python so I'm not sure what else I need to supply to Mathematica for them to be solved.

Comment: The Dirac delta is certainly problematic here. You might consider using e.g. a Gaussian approximation like `Exp[-x^2/(4 h)]/(2 Sqrt[Pi h])` for a sufficiently small value of `h`.

Comment: You're trying to define a point source right? Then you may want to read this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71945/1871 Also, don't forget about boundary condition, [you should already know this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/153338/1871).