# NDSolve aborted

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

I'm trying to simulate the formation of vortices in a BEC condensate with Mathematica. This problem was solved a long time ago (see this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cms/1111095641)).
After making several experiments and changes in the equations and boundary conditions I believe that I need a larger spatial resolution to "see" the vortices. Using a low resolution only gives some resemblance of vortices.
However, when I try to increase the resolution either Mathematica aborts the calculation or the memory grows without control. I'd tried the method described in this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175568/ndsolve-and-memory-used) without success.

The full code is:

```
clearStatus[] := showStatus[""];
clearStatus[];
a = 20;
xl = yl = -a;
xr = yr = a;
tmax = 1.;
α = 0.01;
ϵ = 0.08;
ClearAll[vortex];

vortex[x_, y_] := (1/Sqrt[6 π ] ) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/(6)];

eqn = I (1 + α I)*
Derivative[0, 0, 1][ψ][x,y,t] == -0.5 Laplacian[ψ[x, y, t], {x, y}] + 
  I 0.8 (x D[ψ[x, y, t], {y,1}] - y D[ψ[x, y, t], {x,1}]) 
  + (600 Abs[ψ[x, y, t]]^2 + 
  (x^2 + (1+ϵ) y^2)/2)*ψ[x, y, t];

bcs = {ψ[xl, y, t] == vortex[xl, y], ψ[xr, y, t] == vortex[xr, y], 
ψ[x, yl, t] == vortex[x, yl], ψ[x, yr, t] == vortex[x, yr]};

(* bcs={ψ[xl,y,t] == ψ[xr,y,t],ψ[x,yl,t] == ψ[x,yr,t]};*)

ics = ψ[x, y, 0] == vortex[x, y];

nxy = 200;
sol = First[NDSolve[{eqn, ics, bcs}, ψ, {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, 
       {t,0,tmax}, 
       Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> nxy, "MaxPoints" -> 20 nxy, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, 
        EvaluationMonitor :> showStatus["t = " <> ToString[CForm[t]]]]];
```

I want to solve exactly this equation, with possible different or zero parameters α and ϵ (dissipation and anisotropy). The result must contain vortices, which must appear as holes in "the pie" shown below. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Observation: Please note that the answer given below is not the physical solution to my problem, so I emphasize to preserve the differential equation of this post.

[image: This is like the final solution but the holes must be deeper.]

Answer (score 8):

Why do not you use equation (5.11) from the article cited? In this case, vorticity appears quickly enough and exists long enough. See the code and examples

```
    a = 4;
xl = yl = -a;
xr = yr = a;
tmax = 2;
\[CapitalOmega] = 1.7; \[Beta] = 100; \[Gamma] = -2;
vortex[x_, y_] := ((x + I*y)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]) Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/2];
eqn = Derivative[0, 0, 1][\[Psi]][x, y, t] == 
   0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] - 
    I \[CapitalOmega] (x*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], {y, 1}] - 
       y*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, 
          1}]) - (\[Beta] Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 + \[Gamma]*( 
         x^2 + y^2))*\[Psi][x, y, t];
bcs = {\[Psi][xl, y, t] == vortex[xl, y], \[Psi][xr, y, t] == 
    vortex[xr, y], \[Psi][x, yl, t] == 
    vortex[x, yl], \[Psi][x, yr, t] == vortex[x, yr]};
ics = \[Psi][x, y, 0] == vortex[x, y];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ics, bcs}, \[Psi][x, y, t], {x, xl, xr}, {y, 
     yl, yr}, {t, 0, tmax}]; // Quiet
{Grid[{{"\[CapitalOmega]=", \[CapitalOmega]}, {"\[Beta]=", \[Beta]}, \
{"\[Gamma]=", \[Gamma]}}], 
 Table[ContourPlot[Abs[sol], {x, xl, xr}, {y, yl, yr}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"t=", t}], PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20, 
   PlotPoints -> 50], {t, 0, tmax, .2*tmax}]}
```

[image: fig1]
I tested the method for `NDSolve[]`, which allows investigating the solution of this problem in a wide range of parameters. Here is an example of the formation of quantum vorticity in an electromagnet field:

```
Lx = 4;
Ly = 4;

tmax = 2;
\[CapitalOmega] = 1.3; \[Beta] = 100; \[Gamma][t_] := 
 Sin[2*Pi*t]/Sqrt[2];
vortex[x_, y_] := Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/2];
eqn = Derivative[0, 0, 1][\[Psi]][x, y, t] == 
   0.5 Laplacian[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, y}] - 
    I \[CapitalOmega] (x*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], {y, 1}] - 
       y*D[\[Psi][x, y, t], {x, 
          1}]) - (\[Beta] Abs[\[Psi][x, y, t]]^2 - \[Gamma][
         t - x - y]^2)*\[Psi][x, y, t];
bcs = {\[Psi][-Lx, y, t] == vortex[-Lx, y], \[Psi][Lx, y, t] == 
    vortex[Lx, y], \[Psi][x, -Ly, t] == 
    vortex[x, -Ly], \[Psi][x, Ly, t] == vortex[x, Ly]};
ics = \[Psi][x, y, 0] == vortex[x, y];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ics, bcs}, \[Psi][x, y, t], {x, -Lx, 
    Lx}, {y, -Ly, Ly}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> 100, 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
Table[ContourPlot[Abs[sol], {x, -Lx, Lx}, {y, -Ly, Ly}, Mesh -> None, 
  Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"t=", t}], ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], {t, 0, tmax, .2*tmax}]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, the sign in the potential do not agree with my code, I'll check it. It seems in the paper the potential as the same sign as the non-linear term as well. However, your solution looks correct.

Comment: The authors consider the harmonic attracting potential, whereas I checked the harmonic repulsive potential due to the rotation of the liquid. I could not reproduce their examples. However, my examples are similar to them.

Comment: In my first comment, I didn't realize that the eq 5.11 of the cited paper is not the OP equation. It is the equation for the "normalized gradient flow" method. I'm glad that the vortices shows up, but I'm frustrated for not being able to obtain them from a direct simulation (from eq. 2.5). I suppose Mathematica must be able to perform the integration and that I'm missing something else.

Comment: The rotation is expressed by the angular momentum operator, the harmonic potential only serves to confine the condensate. In order to perform the simulatation with the equation you used it is necesary to renormalize the wave function in each timestep (and change the sign of the potential). This is why we don't get the same solutions.

Comment: If you want to compare your calculations with the results in Fig. 6.1 you should use (5.11). See 6.1. Initial data for computing ground state. … Here we present a 2D example to evolve the CNGF (5.11) with its BEFD discretization for four diﬀerent initial data.

Comment: yes that's correct, but this is not the equation I wanted to solve. It helped me, but it has the wrong parameters as well. I'am trying to obtain similar results as in the paper and couldn't get it, using your solution. Anyway I thank you.

Comment: The article on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10547.pdf contains a detailed description of the methods for integrating the nonlinear Schrödinger equation for a rotating condensate - see Figure 11.

Comment: thank you for the reference, and yes, Figure 11 on that paper is what I'm looking for. See that in your example the potential is repulsive, and because of that the condensate reach the boundaries. If I flip the sign of the potential, the condensate evaporates before forming a lattice.

Comment: My example refers to another task. I have just shown that Mathematica makes it possible to distinguish features in the form of vortices, even at short intervals and on coarse grids. But I was not able to reproduce examples where 1000x 1000 grids and a million steps in time are required

Comment: your solution was useful for me, although it is not the solution to the OP, thank you again.

Comment: I upvoted your answer.