# Solving numerically an initial value problem on an unbounded domain

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity, boundary-conditions

I wish to solve the pde:
$$-\frac{1}{1-t}\partial_x^2\phi+t^4(1-t)\partial_t^2\phi-t^4\partial_t\phi=\mu^2 \phi,$$
with initial conditions $\phi(x,0)=\cos(\mu x)$ and $\dot{\phi}(x,0)=0$ for some time period $t\in[0,0.9]$, for example. Lacking analytical methods, I thought I'd try numerically. However, numerically means I have to give a solver a spacial domain $[-a,a]$ on which to solve... and I have no idea what boundary conditions to impose on $x=\pm a$. In a sense, the value of $\phi$ on spacial slices like $x=a$ are exactly what I'm trying to find in the first place!

How does one get around this?

Comment: Is your question about Mathematica (software) or mathematics? If it is about Mathematica could share the code you have written so far?

Comment: Some progress can be made by Fourier decomposing the solution in `x` to obtain an ODE, which can be solved numerically as a function of the Fourier wavenumber.  Note, however, that eventually boundary conditions in `x` are required. to obtain a unique solution.

Comment: My question is, what does one do in principle to get around this difficulty in evolving a very wide class of problems numerically? I haven't included code because I know that Mathematica (or any solver) will not give me reasonable results as it won't know what to do on the artificial spatial boundaries I have to give to solve on a finite domain.

Comment: Perhaps, since the initial condition is periodic, I could impose periodic boundary conditions to get away with it?

Comment: The initial condition is not periodic unless `mu a` is a multiple of 'Pi`.  If it is, then my earlier comment readily reduces the pde to an ode.  Note, however, that the ode is singular at `t == 0` and `t == 1`.

Comment: I can choose $a$ arbitrarily as it's only necessary for the numerics. I know I can separate variable and reduce it to an ode but I found matching the general solution in this form to the desired initial conditions quite hard.

Comment: “My question is, what does one do in principle to get around this difficulty in evolving a very wide class of problems numerically? ” As I've already mentioned under your question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174776/initial-condition-trouble-with-ndsolve-for-a-2nd-order-pde#comment458816_174776), There's no general solution, AFAIK. The choosing of b.c. approximating infinity highly depends on the physical background of the PDE.